# Determine the default character encoding in a RedHat system

Tags: redhat, encoding

How do I determine the default character encoding in a RedHat system using the command line? I just want to know what encoding a Java app would use per default if none is specified

Answer (score 13):

The [`locale`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/locale) command holds the key to these secrets.
(There are probably other RedHat-specific ways to do this, but `locale` will work on pretty much any *NIX system.)

Answer (score 4):

I had problem with ISO-8859-1 files in a server UTF-8 and I was force to change

You can see de default language using the command:

echo $LANG

Edit the file: /etc/sysconfig/i18n and modify the property. See the example bellow:

LANG="pt_BR.ISO-8859-1"